# GeoServer Mosaic in Production Environment

Tags: geoserver, mosaic, image-mosaic

I am using mosaic plugin to publish an image dataset with about 200 images(800MB each).
The OOM(out-of-memory) errors show up after a period of time when tiling this mosaic layer.
I follow the instructions on the offical website of GeoServer and change the memory limitation of GeoServer with the parameters `-Xms8192m -Xmx24576m -XX:MaxPermSize=8192m`. The server that hosts GerServer has a 12-core CPU and 32GB RAM. But it still break down as before. And I notice the Memory Usage in Geoserver - Server Status shows different occupation with the operating system.

I am using Ubuntu 22 and Geoserver 2.21.0(Java 1.8.0) and no other program is running on this server.Here are my questions:

1. Is it fine that I use mosaic plugin in this situtation? It's mentioned by GeoSolutions(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NCQ5Ba7PRyA) that too many images in a mosaic layer would cause efficiency problem. How many images can be defined as too many? Will this cause any efficiency problem if I tile the layer first?
2. How to optimize the parameters of `-Xms`, `-Xmx2` and `-XX:MaxPermSize`? I saw several versions of materials that suggests Xmx should not be bigger than some kind of threshold, such as 4GB. Is that correct?
3. Is there any memory leak problem in GeoServer 2.21.0? Ubuntu `top` says java(GeoServer) occupies 25% of the memory, i.e., about 8GB. But the status of GeoServer show a 4.9 GB occupation. Please see the following picture for detials.
   [image]

Comment: step one is to move to a supported version - 2.24.0 or 2.23.3 and Java 11 - then follow the [instructions](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/troubleshooting.html#using-jdk-tools-to-get-stack-and-memory-dumps) on how to look for memory problems.

Comment: Maybe you start optimization from a wrong place. Perhaps you should first optimize the data so that rendering would not require so much memory. For example https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340445/serving-large-1-7tb-dataset-of-aerial-images-with-geoserver has some good hints and links for finding more good reading. But 200 images is not much. Are the original images tiled and do they have overviews?

Comment: Thanks for your advice and link! I will try to optimize the original images first.